# UPDATE de múltiples tablas relacionadas utilizando INNER JOIN

Tags: mysqli, sql

He revisado una gran cantidad de foros para resolver mi problema sin éxito alguno. El caso es que por ejemplo tengo 5 tablas (en realidad son más) relacionadas entre si con 1 tabla en común, es decir, la `tabla2`, `tabla3`, `tabla4` y `tabla5` están relacionadas con la `tabla1` a través de su `ID`. Es una tabla dividida en 5 tablas debido a la gran cantidad de datos que se manejan. La estructura que tengo en la consulta es la siguiente:

```
"UPDATE alumno 
    INNER JOIN a_salud ON alumno.idalumno = a_salud.idalumno 
    INNER JOIN a_alimentacion ON alumno.idalumno = a_alimentacion.idalumno 
    INNER JOIN a_sueno ON alumno.idalumno = a_sueno.idalumno 
    INNER JOIN a_juego ON alumno.idalumno = a_juego.idalumno 
    SET 
    alumno.nombre_a = '$no', 
    alumno.apellido_a = '$ap', 
    alumno.direccion = '$di', 
    alumno.edad = '$ed', 
    alumno.fecha_nacimiento = '$fn', 
    alumno.lugar_nacimiento = '$ln', 
    alumno.procedencia = '$pr', 
    alumno.genero = '$ge', 
    a_salud.pediatra = '$ped', 
    a_salud.gpo_sanguineo = '$gs', 
    a_salud.enfermedad_pad = '$epa', 
    a_salud.hospitalizacion = '$ho', 
    a_salud.alergias = '$ale', 
    a_salud.limitacion_motora = '$lm', 
    a_salud.especialista = '$es', 
    a_salud.propenso = '$pro', 
    a_alimentacion.come_solo = '$cs', 
    a_alimentacion.desayuna = '$des', 
    a_alimentacion.apetito = '$ape', 
    a_alimentacion.ahogarse = '$ah', 
    a_alimentacion.comida_favorita = '$cf', 
    a_alimentacion.comida_evita = '$ce', 
    a_sueno.hora_dormir = '$hd', 
    a_sueno.tipo_sueno = '$ts', 
    a_sueno.dormir_con = '$dco', 
    a_sueno.pide_dormir = '$pd', 
    a_juego.juego_favorito = '$jf', 
    a_juego.juguete_favorito = '$jfa', 
    a_juego.objeto_favorito = '$of', 
    a_juego.cuida_juguete = '$cj', 
    a_juego.lugar_jugar = '$lj' 
WHERE alumno.idalumno = '$id'";
```

No es todo el código porque es muy largo, pero el problema que tengo es que no me da ningún error, pero aún así no me modifica ningún campo, si modifico por ejemplo el `gpo_sanguineo` que pertenece a la tabla `a_salud`, cuando reviso los datos nuevamente en realidad no se modificó nada y lo mismo pasa al intentar modificar cualquier otro campo. Estoy empezando en esto y primera vez que me toca actualizar varias tablas así y de verdad ni conocía el `INNER JOIN` y he tratado de entender su estructura y como se usa. Cada una de esas variables están declaras anteriormente y se reciben por `POST` del formulario.

Por favor podría alguien ayudarme con esto? Agradecido de antemano por su colaboración!

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87019/discussion-on-question-by-thelemix-update-de-multiples-tablas-relacionadas-utili).